# Visual Studio 2008 - Microsoft Document Explorer - very small font

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2008

When working with Visual Studio 2008, When I open any help page in Microsoft Document Explorer, the font is so small I can't read it. Under Tools: Options: Environment: Fonts and Colors: Show settings for: I have only 'Environment Font' option (this option changes the font of the application, but doesn't change the font of the displayed webpage).

When I right mouse click on the webpage: Text Size: this is already set to 'Largest'.

Repairing Microsoft Document Explorer from Add and Remove programs didn't help.

How can I fix the font in Microsoft Document Explorer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions under [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc664391.aspx) link:

[image]

[image]